# Nodejs application Error: bind EADDRINUSE when use pm2 deploy

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, express, cluster-computing

Express application deploy with [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

database is mongodb

when run app with command:

`NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js -i max`

aften has Error: bind EADDRINUSE, this is logs, when error,

```
[app err (l0)] js:1073:26
[app err (l1)]     at Object.30:1 (cluster.js:587:5)
[app err (l2)]     at handleResponse (cluster.js:171:41)
[app err (l3)]     at respond (cluster.js:192:5)
[app err (l4)]     at handleMessage (cluster.js:202:5)
[app err (l5)]     at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
[app err (l6)]     at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
[app err (l7)]     at child_process.js:392:7
[app err (l8)]     at process.handleConversion.net.Native.got (child_process.js:91:7)Error: bind EADDRINUSE
[app err (l9)]     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
[app err (l10)]     at net.js:1073:26
[app err (l11)]     at Object.31:1 (cluster.js:587:5)
[app err (l12)]     at handleResponse (cluster.js:171:41)
[app err (l13)]     at respond (cluster.js:192:5)
[app err (l14)]     at handleMessage (cluster.js:202:5)
[app err (l15)]     at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
[app err (l16)]     at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
[app err (l17)]     at child_process.js:392:7
[app err (l18)]     at process.handleConversion.net.Native.got (child_process.js:91:7)
```

This causes app is slow, How to solve this problem, thanks very much

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I don't know the port used by your application. It depends on your code. In this example, I will assume the port is `3000`.

You need to verify if the port is already took on your system. To do that:

- On linux: `sudo netstat -nltp | grep 3000`
- On OSX: `sudo lsof -i -P | grep 3000`

If you have a result, you need to kill the process (`kill <pid>`).

You should check if `pm2 list` returns 0 process. In addition, when you do a `pm2 stopAll`, the socket is not released. Don't forget to do a `pm2 kill` to be sure the daemon is killed.

```
$ pm2 kill
Daemon killed
```

Comment: I get this same error without having any process listed... "pm2 delete all", then "pm2 start app.js", and I still get that error... "sudo netstat -nltp | grep 3000" continues to show nothing...

Comment: I ran into this problem as well. It seems when you exit pm2 using `ctrl+c` it does not actually kill the node process (if you were running a node process). Using the solution above allowed me to find my server and kill it. I would have thought pm2 does this gracefully, but it doesn't. Note I was using an express server.

Comment: it's work very well, i do it on my production, thanks to save my life

Comment: Six years later, this saved my butt today.  Killing the pm2 processes was the key to my errors.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps 6 years later Bill 

Answer (score 8):

**OS X**

Cmd+Space -> enter: Activity Monitor -> find your app and terminate it.

[image]