# Error socket: Error: bind EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:2361 in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, sockets

I have a problem with the node server.
When I try to establish a WebRTC connection with the browser I get this error:

Error socket: Error: bind EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:2361
Error socket: Error: bind EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:1236
node:events:381
throw err; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. ({
ts: 1636713359395,
pid: 2560,
level: 'error',
msg: [ 'Error socket: Error: bind EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:2361' ]
})
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at process.emit (node:events:379:17)
at /opt/WebAppCOM4/node_modules/simple-node-logger/lib/Logger.js:46:25
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR',
context: {
ts: 1636713359395,
pid: 2560,
level: 'error',
msg: [ 'Error socket: Error: bind EADDRINUSE 0.0.0.0:2361' ]
}
}

Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?
Thanks for the replies.

Michele

Comment: something is already using port 2361?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs application Error: bind EADDRINUSE when use pm2 deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18687877/nodejs-application-error-bind-eaddrinuse-when-use-pm2-deploy)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your post by formatting properly the error messages.